# Android Studio Gitlab migration

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, gitlab

I am attempting to migrate a local project to a currently existing empty Gitlab project repo. I have added via the git shell the project's remote origin. I have also enabled git as the VCS in my AS project. I have committed changes from my project, via AS, however no files are showing in my Gitlab webclient.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: What did you do to configure the remote? Adding a remote to a repository created with git init so that it acts like it was cloned from there is a few steps. You need to add the remote with `git remote add <name> <repo>`, then push and set the upstream branch of your local branch with `git push -u <remote>`

Answer (score 0):

So you say you have an empty Gitlab project.
Then you said that you have:

- Added remote origin, via shell (git remote add origin https:/ /gitlab.com/user/repo.git, right?)
- Enabled git as the VCS in your Android Studio project (*VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration*, and then selected Git from the *Select a version control system to associate with the project root:*, right?)
- Commited changes to your project, via Android Studio (*VCS -> Git -> Commit Directory*, right?)

That is all ok, you are only missing a push to the remote, `git push -u <remote>` from the command line, or *VCS -> Git -> Push* from Android Studio.

If you are using Gitlab then Android Studio *Gitlab Projects* plugin will be very useful to you.  Check it out from Android Studio in *File -> Settings*, then *Plugins*, then *Browse Repositories...*

**tl;dr**

Given the steps you have already done, I would say you are only missing a push to the remote, as @Darren said, `git push -u <remote>`. Now, if you want to manage everything from Android Studio, install *Gitlab Projects* plugin.